# excel vba suppress "downloading file" message

Tags: vba, excel

I realize this question has been asked before, but the supplied answers did not solve the problem.  I'm running VBA code from within Excel which does the following:

1.) Open a local worksheet (i.e. C:\desktop\AOR\Names.xlsx)

2.) Read down column B getting the names of files that need to be verified

3.) Open the filename (as taken from column B) from a Network drive.

4.) Verify some cells from the opened file

5.) Close the file.

6.) Iterate.

All this is working with no problems; my situation is that when the file is opened from the Network drive (i.e. step 3) I get the "Downloading File" message.  The only option on this is "Cancel" or let it go to completion.  Pressing cancel (or using SendKeys to do so) causes the file open to cancel, thus stopping the rest of the process.  I've had users accidentally press this cancel enough times that I want to suppress the dialog box completely but cannot find anything that works.

Here is some code with the options I've tried all to no avail:

```
WhatName = Workbooks(AgencyNamesList).Worksheets("Agencies").Range("B" & i).Value ' get name of file from locally opened workbook.

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False ' Prevent code in workbook from running
' Application.SendKeys "{ESCAPE}", False ' Cancels subsequent file opens
' Application.SendKeys "{ESCAPE}", True '  Cancels the file open
' Application.SendKeys "~", True '         Cancels the file open

QuarterDueDate = Workbooks.Open(SourceFolder & WhatName).Worksheets("YTD").Range("I6").Value ' open book get value of I6
```

This [page](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/a9ed04ff-a75f-4905-9e9d-21062e9fddd1/hide-network-download-progress?forum=exceldev) shows a picture of the dialog box along with someone else trying to find a solution (since 2012) to this problem.

OPSYS: Windows 7 Enterprise SP1

EXCEL: MS Office Professional Plus 2013

I'm sure hoping someone has found a way to prevent this pop-up box from popping!

NOTE: When this code is run against the same files stored locally, the dialog box does NOT display.

Thanks!

Comment: When the user hits cancel, does that throw an error? Maybe you could capture that error, throw up a `MsgBox` reminding your user NOT to hit cancel, then continue the process back from where it stopped?

Comment: If you make a local copy as a part of your script, you won't get the message. If you're only reading the file, it might be the easiest way to suppress the dialog.

Comment: I can't repo this.  When I open a file from a network drive I don't get the popup dialog, but I do get a display on the [status bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3FZm.jpg) .  Pressing ESC while opening causes a VBA error, which can be handled in whatever way you choose, including restarting the Open. (Using Win 7 and Excel 2010)

Comment: Thank you ALL for your helpful suggestions.  I was hoping to avoid those routes, but it looks like that's the way I'm going to have to go.